# Usage of not yet in a sentence

Tags: grammar

Is it proper to say,

> not yet showing

in a database?  Or should the sentence be

> not shown yet

in a database?  Please advise, thank you.

Comment: Both of your phrases can be used and would be understood. Would you have complete sentence examples?

Comment: *Not yet* is fine, but I don't think it's entirely idiomatic to say either that some object *is shown* (transitive/passive) or *is showing* (intranstive/active) in a database. I'd prefer *has not yet shown up* or (more formally) *has not yet appeared* .

Comment: Very casual idiom: The data hasn't *hit the system* yet.

Answer (score 1):

Both of your phrases can be used and would be understood.

> They new records are **not showing *up* yet**.
>   The new records ***have not shown up yet***.

You could also use

> The new records are ***not available*** yet.

Using *not showing* implies you are looking at some front-end application which is trying to display the new records, using *not available* implies nothing is able to access the new records.

@StoneyB is correct, in a database situation, because actions are atomic, either the data is in the database or it isn't.  The situation you describe usually results from some delay in the entry or display of the information.